# Understand which viewport is returned from document.documentElement.clientWidth/Height, and difference with window.innerHeight/innerWidth

Tags: javascript, dom, viewport

I am a bit confused about the concept of *viewport* in JavaScript and in the DOM, especially `document.documentElement.clientWidth` that should return the width of the viewport.

In fact, `document.documentElement` is the `html` element, and regardless  if I already set a fixed width in px of the `html` element, `clientWidth` will return the viewport dimension.

Now, when I studied CSS I learned that the mobile browser has two viewports, the default viewport and the ideal viewport. The *default* viewport is useful for a browser without responsive techniques. The *ideal* viewport is the viewport used when I have provided RWD mechanism (In this case I have to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and media query ).

For example, the iPhone 5 has a physical screen width of 640 px, but its ideal viewport is 320 px.  Furthermore, there is the concept of *visual viewport* and *layout viewport* that comes into play when there is zoom, for instance.

Now I would like to know from `document.documentElement.clientWidth` which viewport dimension returns both on desktop computer and mobile phone (if there are differences). Because I tried, and I find that `window.innerWidth/Height` (the browser content area) is almost always the same value of `document.documentElement.clientWidth/Height`(except for scroll, margin, and border pixel values).

How is it possible?   Is there a different meaning of "viewport" in JavaScript DOM that I'm missing?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Experiment</title>
   <style>

      p{
         float:right;
         width:20%;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

  <p id="par">Hello</p>

   <script>

      console.log(window.innerHeight);
      console.log(window.innerWidth);
      console.log(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
      console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
      console.log(screen.height);
      console.log(screen.width);

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

results in (I'm in remote debug from my pc to my Samsung Galaxy A5, with a local server that serve my web page ):

```
560//browser window viewport (innerHeight)
360
560//viewport (document.documentElement.clientHeight)
360
640 //screen size
360
```

The viewport and the browser viewport are the same. I can accept it so far. Now the same page but I  get out of the way this metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and i get:

```
1524 //browser window viewport (innerHeight)
980
1524 //viewport (document.documentElement.clientHeight)
980  
640 //screen size
360
```

How I expected the viewport size is changed without the meta tag, because the page is mapped on the **default viewport** (1540x980) and later will be shrunk in the physical pixel (640x360 less or more).

Ok, but I don't understand why the browser window viewport (`innerHeight\innerWidth`) still has the same dimensions of viewport (`clientWidth|clientHeight`). I would have expected that browser windows viewport to remain 560x640.

Can someone give me an explication about this?

I tested this on Google Chroome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSSOM View spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1) defines both [window.innerHeight/Width](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-window-innerwidth) and [document.documentElement.clientHeight/Width](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-element-clientwidth) in terms of the *same* viewport, just differing in whether the scrollbars are included or not, so they should always change together.

*Which* notional viewport gets used is not defined there though. Because it is formally defined by a standard, I think we can take it that it uses the *actual viewport* as described in the [CSS Device Adaptation spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#actual-viewport).

Comment: I took a look the links. Both methods refer the same viewport. Furthermore, the viewport should be related to the actual viewport that is a preset browser dependent and can be set from the user agent stylesheet or overidden from media query. Thus this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window to determine window size is wrong. Namely it isn't sure use neither window.innerWidth nor document.documentElement.clientWidth

Comment: @Umbert - Historically, browsers have been all over the place with these properties. I note that the accepted answer there was written almost 10 years ago and much has changed in that time. The answers on that linked question are often trying to fill in the gaps in implementations of what are now very old browsers.

Comment: Thus, nowdays How can I get the browser window size? I understand intuitively that the procedure in the previous link now is still fine for desktop browser but can be misleading for mobile browser. I know this is another question.